# 2D Compass heading from AbsoluteOrientationSensor quaternion for the normal to the back of the smartphone. Gimbal lock issue

Tags: javascript, math, sensors, webapi, quaternions

I need to get the angle of rotation of the smartphone(device) with respect to north(0 - 360 degrees)
I am interested in the angle from the normal, from the back cover of the device (where the camera eye is). No matter how the device does not rotate, I am interested in exactly which way the back cover is looking relative to the 0th degree.
Let's imagine that the phone is a window. And I want to understand where I look through this window, north or south. That said, I'm free to rotate my smartphone in all directions.

I feel that the quaternion that returns AbsoluteOrientationSensor has all the information I need, but the formula I found to convert to compass direction is prone to the gimbal lock problem.
Here is the recalculation using this formula (javascript):

```
 const quaternionToHeading = function(q) {
        let [x, y, z, w] = q;
        let a = Math.atan2(2*x*y + 2*z*w, 1 - 2*y*y - 2*z*z)*(180/Math.PI);
        if(a < 0) a = 360 + a;
        return (360 - a).toFixed(1);
    }
```

As a result I have the correct compass value, but not in all cases.

1. For example, when I hold the smartphone with the screen directly in front of me and rotate it around (yaw) I can see the correct compass value.

[image]

2. When I turn the Smartphone parallel to the ground and rotate it around me (yaw) in this position, I also see the correct value.

[image]

3. But, if I turn (roll) the smartphone from the portrait position, but holding it the same way in the north direction with the back cover normal, the compass value changes unpredictably.

[image]

Please help me find a solution.

Demo application (for roll test need be running from smartphone, pc browser does not not support orientation lock):
https://www.arkon.solutions/static/quaternioncompass/index.html

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.board {
    color: white;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 3em;
}

.control-block {
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.control-block__message {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="module">

    const board = document.querySelector(".board");
    const lblHeading = document.querySelector("#lblHeading");
    const lblSide = document.querySelector("#lblSide");
    
    const options = { frequency: 60, referenceFrame: "device" };
    const sensor = new AbsoluteOrientationSensor(options);
    sensor.addEventListener("reading", () => {
        let heading = quaternionToHeading(sensor.quaternion);
        let side = headingToSide(heading);
        let color = headingToColor(heading);
        lblHeading.innerHTML = Math.round(heading) + '°';
        lblSide.innerHTML = side;
        board.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
    sensor.addEventListener("error", (error) => {
    if (event.error.name === "NotReadableError") {
        console.log("Sensor is not available.");
    }
    });
    sensor.start();


    //Magic here
    const quaternionToHeading = function(q) {
        let [x, y, z, w] = q;
        let a = Math.atan2(2*x*y + 2*z*w, 1 - 2*y*y - 2*z*z)*(180/Math.PI);
        if(a < 0) a = 360 + a;
        return (360 - a).toFixed(1);
    }

    const headingToSide = function(heading) {
        //N 
        //E 45 - 145
        //S 135 - 225
        //W 225 - 315

        //NE 22.5 - 67,5
        //E 67,5 - 112,5
        //ES 112,5 - 157,5
        //S 157,5 - 202,5
        //WS 202,5 - 247,5
        //W 247,5 - 292,5
        //WN 292,5 - 337,5
        //N - rest
        let result = 'N';
        if (heading > 22.5 && heading <= 67.5) {
            result = 'NE';
        } else if (heading > 67.5 && heading <= 112.5) {
            result = 'E'
        } else if (heading > 112.5 && heading <= 157.5) {
            result = 'SE';
        } else if (heading > 157.5 && heading <= 202.5) {
            result = 'S';
        } else if (heading > 202.5 && heading <= 247.5) {
            result = 'SW';
        } else if (heading > 247.5 && heading <= 292.5) {
            result = 'W';
        } else if (heading > 292.5 && heading <= 337.5) {
            result = 'NW';
        }
        return result;
    }

    const headingToColor = function(heading) {
        let southLevel = heading;
        if (heading > 180) {
            southLevel = 360 - heading;
        }
        
        let r = 0,
            g = 0,
            b = 0;
        r = Math.round(255 * southLevel / 180);
        b = 255 - r;
        
        return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
    }

</script>
<script>


    function showMessage(msg) {
        document.querySelector('.control-block__message').innerHTML = msg;
    }
    
    function switchFullScreen(elem = document.body) {

        if (!!document.fullscreenElement) {
            let fnRequestExitFullScreen = null;
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                fnRequestExitFullScreen = document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
                fnRequestExitFullScreen = document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                fnRequestExitFullScreen = document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
            fnRequestExitFullScreen.then(() => {
                screen.orientation.unlock();
                this.showMessage("Please, switch app to fullscreen mode");
            }).catch(ex => {
                alert(ex);
            });
        } else {
            let fnRequestFullscreen = null;
            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                fnRequestFullscreen = elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
                fnRequestFullscreen = elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                fnRequestFullscreen = elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            fnRequestFullscreen.then(() => {
                return screen.orientation
                    .lock("portrait")
                    .then(() => {
                        this.showMessage("Ok, app is ready to test now");
                    }).catch((ex) => {
                        alert(ex);
                    });
            }).catch(ex => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(ex));
            });
        }
        
    }

    function onFullscreenClick() {
        this.switchFullScreen(document.body);
    }

</script>
<body>
    <div class="board">
        <span id="lblHeading"></span>
        <span id="lblSide"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="control-block">
        <div class="control-block__message">Please, switch app to fullscreen mode</div>
        <button onclick="onFullscreenClick()">Full screen + Lock orientation</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Glitch project:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/frequent-parallel-antimatter

Comment: Remember that your post should contain [all the details](/help/how-to-ask), including all the ([mcve]) code. Links to external sites are fine but _only_ in addition to having the relevant code in your post. Stackoverflow has a built-in "runnable snippet" functionality for putting plain html/js/css code directly into your post with a "run" button.

Comment: you're right, I pasted the code here, for whoever would feel comfortable copying for a test into their editor (I hope so).

Comment: If I compare it with the iOS compass it still has a difference of 20 degrees. I worked on this problem a while, but I never was able to get reliable readings on Android in the browser. Don't get that in the time of AR this is not a simple API like iOS offers with webkitCompassHeading.